# How to add ApiKey schema validation as the second validation schema to a WebApi in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, api-key, .net-core-authorization

I have a Web API that as already `JwtBearer` schema validation in place. Now I need to add `ApiKey` schema validation to the Web API to be used by a service.

I follow this [guide](http://codingsonata.com/secure-asp-net-core-web-api-using-api-key-authentication/), create the `ApiKeyAttribute` class and decorated the controller method with `[ApiKey]` attribute.

Still, when I call the Web API method, I get the 401 error.

Here is how the call is made:

```
//add "Authentication: Bearer somekey" header to every http call
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("ApiKey", "somekey");
```

The method `OnActionExecutionAsync` of `ApiKeyAttribute` class is never called.

I try to add the Authentication schema like this to the Web API startup with no success at all:

```
builder.Services    
 .AddControllers().Services
 .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
 ...
 .AddAuthentication("ApiKey").Services //the second schema, ApiKey
 .Add...
```

Instead, it returns

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no
> DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using
> either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
> AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

Any clues?

**Update 25-04-2002**

For the sake of completeness, i add here the code of all relevant parts. It works fine with `Bearer` scheme before i try to add `ApiKey` scheme at start.

The attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ApiKeyAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private const string APIKEYNAME = "ApiKey";
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ApiKeyAttribute  HIT !!!"); //not passing here
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEYNAME, out var extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult()
            {
                StatusCode = 401,
                Content = "Api Key was not provided"
            };
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEYNAME);

        if (!apiKey.Equals("TESTE"))
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult()
            {
                StatusCode = 401,
                Content = "Api Key is not valid"
            };
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

The controller with the decorated method with `ApiKey`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]

public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
...

    [HttpGet()]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    //[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Read)] removed temporarily so i can put ApiKey scheme before i enable again the Bearer scheme that allows Role authorization. It is desirable to enable both schemes on same methods. 
    [ApiKey]
    public List<Rule> foo() {
      ...
    }
}
```

Program:

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 ... //configs
 builder.Services    
 .AddControllers().Services
 .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
 ...
 .AddAuthentication("ApiKey").Services //the second schema, ApiKey
 .Add...

var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;
app.Run();
```

**Update 26-04-2026**

Using the Attribute class don't seem to be the way to implement ApiKey schema validation, or at least i failed to put it to work.

I change the `ApiKey` schema validation implementation to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72014134/2700303). Works well as the only schema validation.
Still need to find out how to add it as the second validation schema.

Comment: Hi @MiguelSlv, did you add `app.UseAuthentication();` middleware? Also`UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must be called in the order.

Comment: Hello @Rena, yes i did in that order. I just added an update to the post will the code of all relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Authentication Scheme to the controller explicitly.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    // ACTIONS
}
```

To set the second Authentication Scheme, You can use the below approach:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + apiKey.ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    // ACTIONS
}
```

Comment: It throws the error ´System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("ApiKey",...)?
´. Looks ApiKeyScheme won't work only with Attributes class as posted in the guide i 'm following. I went one step back  and implement the a ApiKey Schema handler and post it here :https://stackoverflow.com/q/72012119/2700303 . Works as a charm.
Now, still need to figure out how use both schemas, Jwt and ApiKey

Comment: with your tip was easy to add the second schema, just added `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + apiKey.ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`. Change your answer and i will accept it, your answer put me on the right track. I going to change the title, so it's clear from start that the point is to add a second schema.

Comment: @MiguelSlv I updated the answer. and add/edit if you have extra info.